# In creating a new table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `Company`. Now I need to copy the contents of table `Company` in a new table `Employee` (that too while creating the `Employee` table). I just used the query shown below, but its showing an ERROR.

```
 Create Table Employee as (Select * from Company)
```

Is there any other solution for this....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [`INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
Select * into Employee from Company
```

Comment: The point of `INTO` is that it will create the table if it does not exist